# Change input value using ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I wanted to change an input value based on the selection from a combobox in codeigniter. I tried to code it but theres nothing to be displayed.
Here is my code in my controller.....

```
function fill_info()
{
    // retrieve the group and add to the data array
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
    $data = "0.00";
    if($group_id)
    {
        $this->load-model('Base_amount_setting_model');
        $baseamount = $this->Base_amount_setting_model->getbaseamount($group_id);
        $data .= $baseamount;
        echo $data;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

And in my Base_amount_setting_model there is this method....

```
function getbaseamount($group_id)
{
    $this->db->where('group_id',$group_id);
    $baseamount = $this->db->get('base_amount_setting')->row()->amount;
    if($baseamount -> num_rows() == 1)
    {
        return $baseamount->result();
    }
}
```

And there in my view the ajax looks like this.....

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() 
    {
        $("#group_id").change(function() 
        {
            var group_id = $("#group_id").val();
            $.ajax({
                type : "POST",
                url  : "<?php echo base_url('payment/fill_info'); ?>",
                data : "group_id=" + group_id,
                success: function(data) 
                {
                    $("#base_amount").html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and finally my form is like this...

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="select01">Group Id </label>
    <div class="controls">
        <select class="chzn-select" name="group_id" id="group_id" placeholder="Group Id" value="<?php echo $group_id; ?>">
            <option></option>
            <?php
            if (count($groups)) {
                foreach ($groups as $list) {
                    echo "<option value='". $list['group_id'] . "'>" . $list['group_name'] . "</option>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <label for="int" class="err"><?php echo form_error('group_id') ?></label>
    </div>
    <input class="input-xlarge disabled" id="base_amount" name="base_amount" type="text" placeholder="Base Amount" disabled="">
    <input class="input-xlarge disabled" id="total_members" type="text" placeholder="Total Members" disabled="">
</div>
```

Thank You!

Comment: you should change  $("#base_amount").val(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm really curious - but i think your model doesnt return anything
try the following

```
function getbaseamount($group_id)
{
    $query = $this->db
        ->where('group_id',$group_id)
        ->get('base_amount_setting');

    if ($query->num_rows() == 1)
    {
        $obj = $query->row();
        return $obj->amount;
    }
}
```

and as others suggested

change your script code to

```
$("#base_amount").val(data);
```

and your controller function should look like

```
function fill_info()
{
    // retrieve the group and add to the data array
    $group_id = $this->input->post('group_id');
    $data = "0.00";
    if($group_id)
    {
        $this->load-model('Base_amount_setting_model');
        $baseamount = $this->Base_amount_setting_model->getbaseamount($group_id);
        echo $baseamount;
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $data;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change this `$("#base_amount").html(data);`
to `$("#base_amount").val(data);`

Comment: That was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you get your value after ajax hit in `data` object 
then only change this :

```
$("#base_amount").html(data);
```

to

```
$("#base_amount").val(data);
```

Actually `.html` replce the html not change the value.